# Division by power of 2 with round toward zero

Tags: c, division

I need to compute a number (a/(2**b) using only bitwise operators such as ! & ^ ~ and shifts. I was given the following hint but I'm new to C and I dont know what the code means:

```
int bias = x>0 ? 0 : ((1<<n)-1);
```

Can anyone explain it to me?

I thought a>>b would work but I dont think it works for negative numbers.

Comment: `a>>b` performs correct algebraic division (which 'rounds' down), but if you want to round towards zero, you have to make a special effort. By the way, why not write `x/(1<<n)` and look at the assembly code the compiler generates? That should suggest an idea for the way to write it in C.

Comment: doesnt a>>b do integer division? if it is 15/2**1=7. 1111>>1 = 0111?

Comment: `a>>b` performs an operation that is implementation-defined when `a` is negative.  It's perfectly allowable for it to do a logical shift, which creates a fairly useless result.

Comment: @caf: Is there any efficient 100% portable way to code the operation which `x >>= 4` would compute on most machines?  The best I can figure would be `x = x < 0 ? (unsigned)x >> 4 : ((unsigned)x >> 4) - ((signed)((~0u) >> 4) + 1);`, but that's rather icky.  Using `/` seems even worse, since the compiler will generate extra code to produce an unwanted adjustment on negative values which one will then have to undo.

Comment: @supercat: `x < 0 ? (x - 15) / 16 : x / 16` is a twos complement arithmetic right shift by 4, as long as `x - 15` does not overflow, but you're right - the gcc optimiser at least does not seem to notice this.

Comment: @caf: On most compilers (I wouldn't surprised if exceptions exist, but I know of none), signed division is slower than unsigned.  If one is going to have to add special code to deal with negative operands, I would think one may as well arrange things to use the slightly-faster unsigned division `x < 0 ? (signed)(-(-1u-x)/16u)-1 : (signed)(x/16u)`.  I'm curious whether there are any C11 compilers where -1>>1 != -1?  If a language philosophy is supposed to be "don't pay for what you don't use", I would think a division operator whose behavior is unspecified with negative operands...

Comment: ...would make sense, since unless there are some uses for truncated division I'm unaware of, code will almost always either be dividing only positive numbers, won't care about off-by-one errors, or will have to handle positive and negative cases separately for other reasons and could just as easily make both operands to the division positive as leave them negative.  In the second case, the fastest way of computing a value that's less than one away from the exact quotient would seem appropriate.  In the first and third, unsigned division could be even better.

Comment: @supercat: Well, gcc at least propagates sufficient value range information to optimise the `x / 16` in the non-negative branch of the conditional to a simple `sar` on x86.  It's only the negative side of the conditional that uselessly adds and subtracts 15 before the shift.

Comment: @caf: That's interesting to know, though unless the compiler can recognize that the conditional shouldn't be necessary in the first place it's going to be inefficient, in addition to being hard to read.

Comment: @supercat: Well yes - *ideally* the optimiser would see that it is adding and subtracting a constant `15` in the negative branch and squash those, leaving a single `sar`; then it should see that both branches are the same and remove the branch entirely.  At the moment the sticking point seems to be that it's still doing `sarl $31, <x>` in the negative path to obtain the sign, even though that's a constant -1 in that branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That particular bit of code gives you a bias of 0 if x is positive. Otherwise it produces a mask of the lower n bits. The `x = a ? b : c;` pattern is called the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a)(technically the 'conditional operator', apparently) in C.

```
n      (1<<n)    (1<<n)-1     binary
0        0x01       0x00     00000000
1        0x02       0x01     00000001
2        0x04       0x03     00000011
3        0x08       0x07     00000111
4        0x10       0x0F     00001111
5        0x20       0x1F     00011111
6        0x40       0x3F     00111111
7        0x80       0x7F     01111111
           ...
```

Comment: In spite of that wiki page's description, I don't think I've ever heard anyone call ?: the 'conditional operator', it's always been the 'ternary operator', at least whenever anyone's known what to call it at all.

Comment: It'll probably continue to be called the "ternary operator" til someone comes up with a new ternary operator.  Then the term will be confusing.  "Conditional operator", however, will remain unambiguous.

Comment: I don't really get the otherwise part. Say if n = 5, then the variable bias = 00011111 in binary?

Comment: [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) calls it the "conditional operator" - § 6.5.15.

Comment: @Dan: yes, if n=5 bias will be set to 11111 (leading zeroes depends on the variable size, of course)

Answer (score 0):

well,`x<<n` works correctly for positive numbers. so why dont you just use something like 
    `result=if sign=1 then (x<<n) else(-x<<n)`
(replace the iftehenelse by some masking with the sign bit)

Answer (score -1):

Sigh... this is a homework question.  The student is asking for help with an assignment from the Computer Systems, a Programmers' Perspective textbook.

For future reference, any time someone says "I'm only allowed to use the XYZ operators to do something", it's probably a homework question.

I don't suppose there's a way to take reputation away from people who ask for help with homework questions, is there?